# Global snippets in vim

Tags: vim, code-snippets, snipmate

I use snipMate in Vim, and try to use certain snippets in *any* type of file. But I could only find ways of relating snippets to specific filetypes. Is there a way to set 'global' snippets?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Define a _.snippets file in your snippets directory and puts there your global snippets